# Directx 11 Blue Screen of Death when Running my Program

Tags: c++, directx, bsod

I'm trying to use the following code:

```
HRESULT hResult;
HDC hDC;
IDXGISurface1 *pSurface = NULL; 
hResult = m_flashTexture->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGISurface1), (void**)&pSurface); 
hResult = pSurface->GetDC(TRUE, &hDC);                  
assert(SUCCEEDED(hResult));  
m_flashPlayer->DrawFrame(hDC);
```

Where drawFrame is...

```
void CFlashDXPlayer::DrawFrame(HDC dc)
{
if (m_dirtyFlag)
{
    IViewObject* pViewObject = NULL;
    m_flashInterface->QueryInterface(IID_IViewObject, (LPVOID*) &pViewObject);
    if (pViewObject != NULL)
    {
        // Combine regions
        HRGN unionRgn, first, second = NULL;
        unionRgn = CreateRectRgnIndirect(&m_dirtyRects[0]);
        if (m_dirtyRects.size() >= 2)
            second = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 1, 1);

        for (std::vector<RECT>::iterator it = m_dirtyRects.begin() + 1; it != m_dirtyRects.end(); ++it)
        {
            // Fill combined region
            first = unionRgn;
            SetRectRgn(second, it->left, it->top, it->right, it->bottom);
            unionRgn = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 1, 1);

            CombineRgn(unionRgn, first, second, RGN_OR);
            DeleteObject(first);
        }

        if (second)
            DeleteObject(second);

        RECT clipRgnRect; GetRgnBox(unionRgn, &clipRgnRect);
        RECTL clipRect = { 0, 0, m_width, m_height };

        // Fill background
        if (m_transpMode != TMODE_FULL_ALPHA)
        {
            // Set clip region
            SelectClipRgn(dc, unionRgn);

            COLORREF fillColor = GetBackgroundColor();
            HBRUSH fillColorBrush = CreateSolidBrush(fillColor);
            FillRgn(dc, unionRgn, fillColorBrush);
            DeleteObject(fillColorBrush);

            // Draw to main buffer
            HRESULT hr = pViewObject->Draw(DVASPECT_TRANSPARENT, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, dc, &clipRect, &clipRect, NULL, 0);
            assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
        }
        else
        {
            if (m_alphaBlackDC == NULL)
            {
                // Create memory buffers
                BITMAPINFOHEADER bih = {0};
                bih.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
                bih.biBitCount = 32;
                bih.biCompression = BI_RGB;
                bih.biPlanes = 1;
                bih.biWidth = LONG(m_width);
                bih.biHeight = -LONG(m_height);

                m_alphaBlackDC = CreateCompatibleDC(dc);
                m_alphaBlackBitmap = CreateDIBSection(m_alphaBlackDC, (BITMAPINFO*)&bih, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&m_alphaBlackBuffer, 0, 0);
                SelectObject(m_alphaBlackDC, m_alphaBlackBitmap);

                m_alphaWhiteDC = CreateCompatibleDC(dc);
                m_alphaWhiteBitmap = CreateDIBSection(m_alphaWhiteDC, (BITMAPINFO*)&bih, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&m_alphaWhiteBuffer, 0, 0);
                SelectObject(m_alphaWhiteDC, m_alphaWhiteBitmap);
            }

            HRESULT hr;
            HBRUSH fillColorBrush;

            // Render frame twice - against white and against black background to calculate alpha
            SelectClipRgn(m_alphaBlackDC, unionRgn);

            COLORREF blackColor = 0x00000000;
            fillColorBrush = CreateSolidBrush(blackColor);
            FillRgn(m_alphaBlackDC, unionRgn, fillColorBrush);
            DeleteObject(fillColorBrush);

            hr = pViewObject->Draw(DVASPECT_TRANSPARENT, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, m_alphaBlackDC, &clipRect, &clipRect, NULL, 0);
            assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

            // White background
            SelectClipRgn(m_alphaWhiteDC, unionRgn);

            COLORREF whiteColor = 0x00FFFFFF;
            fillColorBrush = CreateSolidBrush(whiteColor);
            FillRgn(m_alphaWhiteDC, unionRgn, fillColorBrush);
            DeleteObject(fillColorBrush);

            hr = pViewObject->Draw(DVASPECT_TRANSPARENT, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, m_alphaWhiteDC, &clipRect, &clipRect, NULL, 0);
            assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

            // Combine alpha
            for (LONG y = clipRgnRect.top; y < clipRgnRect.bottom; ++y)
            {
                int offset = y * m_width * 4 + clipRgnRect.left * 4;
                for (LONG x = clipRgnRect.left; x < clipRgnRect.right; ++x)
                {
                    BYTE blackRed = m_alphaBlackBuffer[offset];
                    BYTE whiteRed = m_alphaWhiteBuffer[offset];
                    m_alphaBlackBuffer[offset + 3] = 255 - (whiteRed - blackRed);
                    offset += 4;
                }
            }

            // Blit result to target DC
            BitBlt(dc, clipRgnRect.left, clipRgnRect.top,
                   clipRgnRect.right - clipRgnRect.left,
                   clipRgnRect.bottom - clipRgnRect.top,
                   m_alphaBlackDC, clipRgnRect.left, clipRgnRect.top, SRCCOPY);
        }

        DeleteObject(unionRgn);
        pViewObject->Release();
    }

    m_dirtyFlag = false;
    m_dirtyRects.clear();
    m_dirtyUnionRect.left = m_dirtyUnionRect.top = LONG_MAX;
    m_dirtyUnionRect.right = m_dirtyUnionRect.bottom = -LONG_MAX;
}
}
```

I also should mention that I set up m_flashTexture using the following:

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc;                  
ZeroMemory(&textureDesc, sizeof(textureDesc));                  
textureDesc.Width = width;                  
textureDesc.Height = height;                  
textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;                  
textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;                  
textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;                  
textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;                  
textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;                  
textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE |     D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET;                  
textureDesc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_GDI_COMPATIBLE;  
HRESULT hr = device->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, NULL, &m_flashTexture);
```

Whenever I run this code (there is more to it but it is burried in a bunch of other classes, let me know if you think something else would be useful..) I get a blue screen of death that is caused somewhere in the flashPlayer->drawFrame() function.  I have no idea what is causing the blue screen.

Any ideas or does any one see something that stands out that looks like it would cause a blue screen?

Thanks.

***More Information***

Here is the results from the crash dump

```
ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  
Use '!findthebuild' command to search for the target build information.
If the build information is available, run '!findthebuild -s ; .reload' to set symbol path and   load symbols.

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff80002c01000 nt

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4d41a3e1

READ_ADDRESS: unable to get nt!MmSpecialPoolStart
unable to get nt!MmSpecialPoolEnd
unable to get nt!MmPoolCodeStart
unable to get nt!MmPoolCodeEnd
fffff8814061c6a0 

FAULTING_IP: 
igdpmd64+15a878
fffff880`0697c878 8b0408          mov     eax,dword ptr [rax+rcx]

MM_INTERNAL_CODE:  5

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x50

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80002c283bf to fffff80002c7dc40

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`0a7e5878 fffff800`02c283bf : 00000000`00000050 fffff881`4061c6a0 00000000`00000000     fffff880`0a7e59e0 : nt+0x7cc40
fffff880`0a7e5880 00000000`00000050 : fffff881`4061c6a0 00000000`00000000 fffff880`0a7e59e0     00000000`00000005 : nt+0x273bf
fffff880`0a7e5888 fffff881`4061c6a0 : 00000000`00000000 fffff880`0a7e59e0 00000000`00000005 00000000`00000000 : 0x50
fffff880`0a7e5890 00000000`00000000 : fffff880`0a7e59e0 00000000`00000005 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0xfffff881`4061c6a0


STACK_COMMAND:  .bugcheck ; kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
igdpmd64+15a878
fffff880`0697c878 8b0408          mov     eax,dword ptr [rax+rcx]

SYMBOL_NAME:  igdpmd64+15a878

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: igdpmd64

IMAGE_NAME:  igdpmd64.sys

BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS

Followup: MachineOwner
```

Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: Have you tried updating your video drivers? I'm not very knowledgeable in the area, but it doesn't sound to me like DirectX alone should be capable of causing a blue screen, even if used incorrectly.

Comment: no way to log or step with a debugger to the point closest to the crash?

Comment: Yup I tried that.  And I agree I would not think it would be the way I used directx... you would think it would just be a normal error for that.

Comment: I was able to find a crash dump... I'll edit my post to include the data from that.  I was able to step with a debugger and find that it happens somewhere in the DrawFrame.  I don't like forcing my computer to a blue screen so I didn't keep trying to narrow it down more...

Comment: Please load symbols from the Microsoft symbol server, that will help track it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you write a user space application and it causes a BSoD, then there is certainly a bug in some kernel level code (either the windows kernel itself, or some driver, in this case, it looks like igdpmd64.sys). Simply put, the OS should **never, under any circumstances**, crash due to something a user space application did. So I would look into whether or not there is an upgrade for this driver or not.

However, it is also probable that you have a bug in your code which is using DirectX incorrectly and is triggering this driver bug.

Certainly, I would try to create an absolutely minimal, complete program which triggers the crash. At the very least so you can submit it to the driver writers.